# $resource callback function in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

I set up a method to be called by an ng-click event in my html:

```
<div ng-repeat="section in model.sections">
    <a ng-click="updateSection($index)">
</div>
```

Then in my javascript file, I had the following service:

```
.factory('Sections', function($resource){
    return{
        onUnits: $resource('/api/sections/:uuid/units', {uuid:'@sectionUUID'}, {
            get: {method: 'GET', params:{uuid: '@uuid'}, isArray:true}
        }
    }
}
```

The method being called from the html is:

```
$scope.updateSection = function(index){
    $scope.model.sections[index].sectionUnits = Sections.onUnits.get({uuid: $scope.model.sections[index].sectionUUID}
        ,console.log($scope.model.sections[index])
        );
    }
```

before this update happens,

```
$scope.model.sections[0].sectionUnits == ['d1','d2']
```

which is the list of id's of units associated with this section. This method basically updates this list with the real `unit` objects that looks like:

```
.sectionUnits = [{unitUUID: 'd1',
                  materials: ['m1','m2','m3']
                  }, {... }]
```

in my browser, the code above returns the updated `section` object that I was looking for, with all the `unit` objects nested under the `section`.

However, what I really wanted, was to implement a callback that takes the list of id's of all the `materials` associated with the unit in this updated `section` object, and retrieve them.

If I try that, and have the following call back instead, I get the list of `sectionUnits` that's still just the id's:

```
$scope.updateSection = function(index){
    $scope.model.sections[index].sectionUnits = Sections.onUnits.get({uuid: $scope.model.sections[index].sectionUUID}
        ,console.log($scope.model.sections[index].sectionUnits)
        );
    }
```

I have looked through a lot of SO threads and the original doc, but am kind of stuck at this point.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern that I have encountered the most is to create a resource object, then make assignments in the callback.  So instead of your current `updateSections` function, you would have:

```
$scope.updateSection = function(index) {
    Sections.onUnits.get(
        {uuid: $scope.model.sections[index].sectionUUID},
        function(results) {$scope.model.sections[index].sectionUnits = results}
    )
}
```

I think that in your code the results of the `GET` don't actually get assigned, which is why you're getting back the original array of ids.

Note that the assignment only occurs on successful `GET` of the resource.  You should have a separate callback to handle any errors.

Also remember that services are singletons, so if you're passing it around, be careful to not change `Sections`, or it'll change everywhere else around.

If you wanted to chain requests such that after retrieving a section, you get the materials, then you would do that in your callback, right after the assignment.:

```
$scope.updateSection = function(index) {
    Sections.onUnits.get(
        {uuid: $scope.model.sections[index].sectionUUID},
        function(results) {
            $scope.model.sections[index].sectionUnits = results;
            // Should contain some looping mechanism since results is an array.
            $scope.getMaterials(results);
        }
    )
}
```

A couple of other notes on your code:

- Something seems wrong about your initial method call to get the resource.  At that point, you say that the `sectionUnits` object is an array of strings, but your `updateSection()` method call tries to reference the array as an object.  You say that you can get a console printout, so I'm guessing that it works, but you just made a typo
- It seems like a bad idea to mutate the sectionUnits object from an array of strings to an array objects.  Maybe initialize it as `.sectionUnits = [{unitUUID:'d1'}, {unitUUID:'d2'}]`?
- You may want to take a look at [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular), which basically wraps `$resource` to be a bit more user friendly.  I've found it to be really easy to work with.